# How can I access the current sorting mode of files in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, air

I'm developing an image viewer app and I need to know how the files are sorted in the directory of the image that is opened.

i.e.: are they currently sorted by name? creation date? modified date?
(that way I can properly show the next image when requested)

I'm using Adobe AIR, but I don't mind using a script that can get me that info.

Thanks!

Comment: Never heard about reading of active Explorer window sorting mode. Does it possible without AIR?

Comment: I haven't heard of it either. I know it can be done in C++ and any other language that can access a handle to the explorer window to get stuff like "Folder.document.items".

Comment: In this case you can develop native extension for Windows. Or develop external app and launch it using NativeProcess.